# Can not install GPU Debugging Tools

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I tried to install Android Studio GPU Debugging tools from SDK manager. But it displayed this error:

> To install
>   - GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;1)
>
> Preparing "Install GPU Debugging tools".
>   Trying to install into C:\Users\Ronald\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\gapid\1\ but package "GPU Debugging tools, rev 1.0.3" already exists at C:\Users\Ronald\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\gapid. It must be deleted or moved away before installing into a child directory.
>   Failed packages:
>   - GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;1)

This is the `...\extras\android\gapid\` dir:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Ronald\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\gapid

08/10/2016  14:55    <DIR>          .
08/10/2016  14:55    <DIR>          ..
08/10/2016  20:50    <DIR>          1
08/10/2016  20:50    <DIR>          3
27/06/2016  21:54    <DIR>          android
27/06/2016  21:58            17.518 package.xml
27/06/2016  21:54            17.187 source.properties
27/06/2016  21:54    <DIR>          windows
               2 File(s)         34.705 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  282.628.423.680 bytes free
```

and `...\extras\android\gapid\1\` dir::

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Ronald\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\gapid\1

08/10/2016  20:50    <DIR>          .
08/10/2016  20:50    <DIR>          ..
08/10/2016  20:50    <DIR>          .installer
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
           3 Dir(s)  282.627.383.296 bytes free
```

What was that means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you're already have it at least partially installed.

Go to: `C:\Users\Ronald\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\` and delete `gapid` folder. Then try to install it through  SDK Manager again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved for me. What is that folder for anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the **gapid** folder

```
E:\AndroidStudio\sdk\extras\android\gapid
```